# Crash when delete a record from coredata in SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I make a list for audio items from coredata. after deleting, crash reported as "EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1b8fb693c)", why?

When using

```
ForEach(items, id: \.self)
```

, it works. But My Audio has id property and follow Identifiable protocol.

UPDATE: I found adding a if{} clause will fix crash, but why? Breakpoint at "static UUID.*unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC(*:) ()".

```
struct Test1View: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Audio.fetchAllAudios()) var items: FetchedResults<Audio>
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                if true { // <- this if clause fix crash, but why?
                    HStack {
                        Text("\(item.name)")
                    }
                }
            }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                let index = indexSet.first!
                let item = self.items[index]
                self.context.delete(item)
                try? self.context.save()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

code as following:

```
class Audio: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID
    @NSManaged public var name: String
    @NSManaged public var createAt: Date
}

struct Test1View: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Audio> = FetchRequest<Audio>(entity: Audio.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "createAt", ascending: false)])
    var items: FetchedResults<Audio> { fetchRequest.wrappedValue }
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                HStack {
                    Text("\(item.name)")
                }
            }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                let index = indexSet.first!
                let item = self.items[index]
                self.context.delete(item)
                try? self.context.save()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem as you.

Probably it is a bad idea to use your own `id` property to make it `Identifiable` because Core Data is setting all the properties to `nil` when the object is deleted, even if you declared it differently in your Swift CoreData class.
When deleting your entity, the `id` property gets invalidated and the objects `.isFault` property is set to `true`, but the SwiftUI `ForEach` still holds some reference to this ID object (=your UUID) to be able to calculate the "before" and "after" state of the list and somehow tries to access it, leading to the crash.

Therefore the following recommendations:

1. Protect the detail view (in the `ForEach` loop by checking `isFault`:

```swift
if entity.isFault {
    EmptyView()
}
else {
    // your regular view body
}
```

2. Expect your `id` property to be `nil`, either by defining it accordingly in your core data model as optional

```swift
@NSManaged public var id: UUID?
```

or by **not relying** on the `Identifiable` protocol in the SwiftUI `ForEach` loop:

```swift
ForEach(entities, id: \.self) { entity in ... }
```

or

```swift
ForEach(entities, id: \.objectID) { entity in ... }
```

**Conclusion:** you really do not need to make all your CoreData properties Swift `Optional`s. It's simply important that your `id` property referenced in the `ForEach` loop handles the deletion (=setting its value to `nil`) gracefully.

Comment: great explanation.  thx.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution. How did you arrive at it? I suspected that something might be up in the view, but I couldn't isolate it.

Comment: Nice work! This one had me stumped. Using the swipe to delete worked great, but from another context it would fail. Changed to using the objectID property and it worked great!

Answer (score 3):

I found the reason of crash, must provide optional, because of OC/swift object conversion:

convert

```
class Audio: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID
    @NSManaged public var name: String
    @NSManaged public var createAt: Date
}
```

to

```
class Audio: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var createAt: Date?
}
```

Comment: You saved me! I spent 30 minutes with this error and this solved :)

Comment: Thanks! For me was enough just to set ID to optional.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue over the weekend. It looks like SwiftUI want's to unwrap the value i read from CoreData and as the value is already deleted it crashes.

In my case i did solve it with nil coalescing on all values i use from CoreData.

You can try to provide a default value on your item.name with

```
ForEach(items) { item in
            HStack {
                Text("\(item.name ?? "")")
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have another code, just the same as this sample code, that works fine. I confused. And `ForEach(items, id: \.self)` will fix this code. It will terrible if this is really an issue of CoreData in SwiftUI. I wonder if I make some mistaken in this code.

Comment: Issue is `UUID._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC`, nil pointer. And adding a if true {} clause will fix the crash, but why? `ForEach(items) { item in
                if true {
                    HStack {
                        Text("\(item.name)")
                    }
                }
            }`